# Best design for single parent multiple child in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am creating a project which have below jpa entities(Tables)

1. User (userId as primary key)
2. UserPersonalDetails(userId is primary/Foreign key mapped to userID
   in User table)
3. UserAcadmicsDetails(userId is primary/Foreign key mapped to userID
   in User table)
4. UserPerformace(userId is primary/Foreign key mapped to userID in
   User table)

.
.
.
and so on

I am confused to select a best design/Approach here i.e. OneToOne bidirectional or OneToOne Unidirectional??

My first though is OneToOne unidirectional as the User entity is heavily used in application (Operation such as log in) hence I don't want to fetch other entities while fetching User Object.

Below are my entity code

**USER:**

```
    public class User implements UserDetails {
      @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        Long userId;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        String firstName;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        String lastName;


        @Column(nullable = false,unique=true)
        String email;
// getter setters
}
```

**UserPersonalDetails**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class UserPersonalDetails {

    @Id
    Long userId;


    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @MapsId
    User user;

    Long univercityId;
    Long collageId;
    String address;
    String parentContact;
    String tempAddress;

// getter setters
}
```

But in this approach when I try to delete the user it fails as it have Foreign key contains on other tables.

Can anyone suggest the ideal design here?

Comment: Could you show java code for entities? Do you consider to make last three entities as embeddable types and have one user table?

Comment: @Anthony added my current entities

Answer (score 0):

So as one of the options, if it's possible to have one table. Consider the case with value type instead of entity. So you don't have to worry about life cycle of UserPersonalDetails. Its lifespan is bound to the concrete user instance.

```
   @Entity
   public class User implements UserDetails {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       Long userId;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       String firstName;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       String lastName;

       @Column(nullable = false,unique=true)
       String email;

       UserPersonalDetails userDetails;

       public UserPersonalDetails getUserDetails() { 
           return userDetails;
       }

       public void setUserDetails() { 
           this.userDetails = userDetails;
       }

            // other getter setters
    }


    @Embeddable
    public class UserPersonalDetails {

        @Column(nullable = false)  // would be nested embeddable component
        Long univercityId;

        @Column(nullable = false) // would be nested embeddable component
        Long collageId;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        String address;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        String parentContact;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        String tempAddress;

    // getter setters
    }
```